# how to show the caption div when current item is focused in owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I need to show the caption div when current item is focused.
i am able to show the caption but when second last image focused with cation last image also show caption in loop.

In first loop all caption div show when image is focused but after first loop last image already comes with caption.
when i keep carousel option loop:True when i  keep false i navigate prev and next then i won't get problem . 
for Refrence: http://jsfiddle.net/ROHIT502/1qdurrLz/95/
[Error Image when loop happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Ecd.jpg)
Here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#slider').on('initialized.owl.carousel change.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel ', function (e) {
if (!e.namespace || e.type != 'initialized' && e.property.name != 'position') return;
var current = e.relatedTarget.current()
var items = $(this).find('.owl-stage').children()
//alert(current);
var add = e.type == 'changed' || e.type == 'initialized'
items.eq(e.relatedTarget.normalize(current)).toggleClass('current', add)
}).owlCarousel({
items: 3,
margin: 10,
itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3],
autoplay:true,
autoplayTimeout:2000,
autoplayHoverPause: true,
//autoHeight: true,
responsive: true,
center: true,
dots:false,
nav: true,
loop: true
});
})
```

Comment: please make it more clear 1. what you want? 2. what is happening 3. what have you done?

Comment: 1)I want to show Info below image when image is focused in owl carousel autoplay. if 3 image i am showing then center focus image will show caption  div and first & last image will not show  caption . 2)i am able to show to center image with caption but when l keep loop option true then  after first loop when again same image start scrolling then in last 3 images last image already shows caption center plus last image both shows captions.its happening when loop reach to last image..for ref  http://jsfiddle.net/ROHIT502/1qdurrLz/95/

Comment: so you want the caption to shift down on hover and also the problem is that somehow the last image's caption doesn't disappear after going through all images once?

Comment: Yes. I want shift down Caption when Image is focused and last image caption doesn't disappear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elementStyle = document.getElementByClass("caja").hover.style;

elementStyle.position = "relative";

elementStyle.top = "20px";
```

This will shift the class caja down by 20px on hover
I am sorry but I don't know what's the matter with the last image's caption I have never used owl carousel. btw you can make way beautiful carousel yourself.